# Getting absolute path of a link from web page source

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I want to find absolute path of link from a web page source.
For example in a web page source, there is a line like this:

```
href="lectures/lecture04.pdf"
```

But the absolute path for this is

```
www.abc.com/courses/cs101/lectures/lecture04.pdf
```

Is there a way to get this path in bash shell?

Comment: Do you know URL of the webpage which you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$ wget --convert-links URL
```

From the [`wget` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html), the switch `--convert-links` is described as follows:

> The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will be changed to include host name and absolute path of the location they point to.
>
> Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif (or to ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html will be modified to point to `http://hostname/bar/img.gif`.